# Is there a way to connect google-play data to metabase?

Tags: google-analytics, visualization, data-science, google-play-console, metabase

I want to connect the Metabase to google-play console to retrieve the data like number of install, uninstall, Active Users and do some analysis on the top of it. Can you please help in the process how to link the google-play to Metabase.

Comment: I would also be interested in that :)